# Changing (gradient) color of Game Object due to distance in an AR Application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying to make an AR Application that shows POI's around. These POI's are from different distances, due distance i want to make them in different color with gradient scale.

I have calculated distances of POI's from GPS coordinates with Haversine Formula and tried to change the color due to distance but it doesn't update the color even though change the distance by walking while i see the POI's. I use WorldScaleAr scene for AR. Below code is only for one POI.

```
using System;
using static System.Math;

double[,] coords = new double[,] { { 39.870613, 32.73341 } }; // POI location

void Start()
{
    // get poi Location
    lat1 = Math.PI * coords[0, 0] / 180.0;
    // lat2 = Math.PI * user[0, 0] / 180.0;
    lon1 = Math.PI * coords[0, 1] / 180.0;
    // lon2 = Math.PI * user[0, 1] / 180.0;

}

void Update()
{
    // Get user location
    // Latitude
    x = getLocation.x1.ToString();
    user_lat = Convert.ToDouble(x);
    user_lat_rad = Math.PI * user_lat / 180.0; // Radian
    // Longitude
    y = getLocation.y1.ToString();
    user_lon = Convert.ToDouble(y);
    user_lon_rad = Math.PI * user_lon / 180.0; // Radian

    // Change POIs sizes
    distances = Convert.ToSingle(distance(user_lat_rad, user_lon_rad));
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color((distances*255f/1000f)/255f, (distances*255f/1000f)/255f, (distances*255f/1000f)/255f);

public double distance(double lat2, double lon2)
{
    // Haversine Formula
    // Lat2,Lon2 = User Location
    // Lat1,Lon1 = POI Location
    double dist1 = Sqrt((Pow(Sin((lat2 - lat1) / 2), 2)) + Cos(lat2) * Cos(lat2) * (Pow(Sin((lon2 - lon1) / 2), 2)));
    double distance = 2 * r * Asin(dist1);
    return distance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What values does the distance function return? I'm asking about the order of magnitude of the numerical value. This: distances*255f/1000f)/255f is equal to distance/1000 so you might just as well get values close to zero, or if it's more than 1000 (not sure what the units are here), a >1 value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i looked for magnitude of distance, it has a large value.
I tried another thing to make the change of color. I added a new value 



`float gra = 0;

gra = gra + 1f;

GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color((gra/255f), gra/255f, gra/255f);`


It's color is not changing anyway.

Comment: is the =+1 in Update() ? That's 255 cycles to get to full white color.
Maybe expose that gra value in your editor, just to check if the color changing works (by the look of it, should work). There are quite a few ways of clamping the value between 0 and 1, but I would first Debug the values of 'distance' to get a sense of the typical value and your min and max.

Comment: Yes it is a cycle whatever, i was expecting that the color of POI changes every iteration but it doesn't change, it stay same after first run of code.